# Left Join with multiple Depth in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
                  +------------+
+------------+    | acc_email  |
| account    |    +============+
+============+    | id         |
| id         |<-+-+ account_id |
+------------+  | | email      |
                | +------------+
                |  +------------+
                |  | password   |
                |  |============|
                |  | id         |
                +--+ account_id |
                   | password   |
                   | iterations |
                   | salt       |
                   +------------+
```

The users login  via email, need to find the  account, than find the password.  I got this far:

```
       SELECT * 
         FROM acc_email
    LEFT JOIN account
           ON acc_email.account_id = account.id
```

How do I join and retrieve the account email, account and latest password in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any email_id or account.id in your Schema, but following your design
it must be

```
   SELECT  a.*,ae.email , p.password    
   FROM acc_email ae
        LEFT JOIN account a
             ON ae.account_id = a.id 
        LEFT JOIN password p
             ON p.account_id  = a.id 
   WHERE ae.email = 'abc@test.com'
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes, I made a bunch of mistakes, but using your answer, I was able to complete it with some design changes!  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=94e96eb867ceafb0e73de59e6a19d8cf

Comment: no you have a small bug see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8e33d5ab7c0464655d81adc56bd6075f  and please don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: I think I fixed where "I cant see email_id or account.id in your Schema".  Do you mind editing it out in case someone read it so they are not confused.